# Match pattern with and without spaces

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am using [markjs](https://markjs.io/) to search a page and highlight things that would be considered dice rolls. So it using the regex expression `/([1-9]\d*)?d(?:4|6|8|10|12|20)([+-]\d+)?/i` which actually works pretty well when the text is formatted as so `1d10+2` however if the text has any spaces, it only grabs highlights the first part. For example, if the same thing is written as `1d10 + 2` it will only highlight the `1d10`.

Is there something I can adjust in my regex that will account for spaces around the `+` or `-` symbols?

Comment: Just include `\s*` where ever there is a possibility of spaces. [Shown here](https://regex101.com/r/KQkjUz/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the `\s` for blank spaces, so your regex could be something like this:

```
([1-9]\d*)?d(?:4|6|8|10|12|20)\s?([+-]\s?\d+)
```

Comment: you ever hate when something works on the jsfiddle and not what you're actually trying to get it to work on. This appears to be working on jsfiddle but not my chrome extension. So I'll have to play around some.